# Rendering samples from AudioGraph

Tags: core-audio

What I'm trying to achieve should be simple but obviously I'm misunderstanding something small and basic.

I wrote an AudioGraph which receives its input from a Render callback function (in this case CMSampleBufferRefs from an AVAssetReaderOutput - that part's ok).

I want to render the output (offline processing), basically taking the processed output and writing it back to the AVAssetWriter. From the literature, mailing lists, and Stack Overflow I get that I need to use a GenericOutput output unit.

I could get down to several specific questions but it'd be awesome if someone could just start me off with a basic outline of the steps I need to take in order to achieve that.

Thanks!